# Jquery trigger( "click" ) runs 3 or more time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to simulate a click when I click on a input type text, but that one runs for 3 times and then sends 3 times that request.
This is the code:

```
<input type="text" id="text" value="test">
<input id="myid" class="myclass" type="button" value="sendrequest" data-example-id="id" data-example1-id="test" /> 
$( "#text" ).click(function() { 
    $( "#myid" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

Everything is working well but I don't know why the request runs for 3 times.
Is there also the possibility to delete the input type text, doing it from jquery, in case I want to execute it after a keyup jquery function ?

Thanks

Comment: This is not reproducible based on what you've shown here. Could you post more code?

Comment: Appears to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/DJAE2/

Comment: Are you clicking it three times??

Comment: I'm going to second Adam here, more code is needed as the code posted works fine. Chances are good that if this is where you're looking for the problem, it's not where you're going to find your solution. Point being, something else on your page is interacting with the click behavior of the text input.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this jQuery code,

```
<script>
  $( "#text" ).click(function() {
    alert("textbox event is fired")
    var a= $( "#myid" ).trigger( "click" );
  });
  $('#myid').click(function(a) {
    alert("click event triggred on button");
  });
</script>
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: What's this supposed to show? It's usually a good idea to explain your answer, rather than just dumping code.

Answer (score 0):

If it runs 3 times, it's because it's being called 3 times. Since you're using jQuery and not attaching callbacks directly, it's likely that you've registered the same callback to the event 3 times.

EDIT: It would help to have some code. Try this code and see if it runs only once.

```
$('#text').off('click.myclick').on('click.myclick', function() { /* your code here */ });
```